# Android graphview and data plotting timing issue?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-graphview

I am currently attempting to "fix" an Android application intended to control a device over BLE. The application was written entirely by someone else, and I currently know very little Java. So if there are glaring flaws please just point them out and I'll fix them. I won't be able to give the rationale very everything you see here, but I'll do my best. While there are a myriad of problems and things to fix, my current issue is the data plotter. GraphView was implemented to create the plots. The issue is that the data plotted is not representative of the actual sampling rate. When using a separate BLE data logger I can verify that the data is being sent at the correct rate and it plots out correctly using excel.

These are created on startup.

```
graph1 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
airPressureSeries = new LineGraphSeries<>();
fluidPressureSeries = new LineGraphSeries<>();
airPressureSeries.setDrawAsPath(true);
fluidPressureSeries.setDrawAsPath(true);
graph1.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph1.getViewport().setMinX(0);
graph1Num = 100;
graph1.getViewport().setMaxX(graph1Num);

graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph2);
airTemperatureSeries = new LineGraphSeries<>();
fluidTemperatureSeries = new LineGraphSeries<>();
airTemperatureSeries.setDrawDataPoints(true);
fluidTemperatureSeries.setDrawDataPoints(true);
graph2.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph2.getViewport().setMinX(0);
graph2Num = graph1Num;
graph2.getViewport().setMaxX(graph2Num);
```

Then this is done when data plotting is to be shown.

```
plot1Dropdown.setText("Air Pressure");
graph1.addSeries(airPressureSeries);
plot1Title.setText(R.string.pressureTitle);
plot2Dropdown.setText("Fluid Pressure");
plot2Title.setText(R.string.pressureTitle);
graph2.addSeries(fluidPressureSeries);
```

This timer, which I don't quite understand and could be wrong, is started. They said it should run at 100Hz. The code inside it should just increment an x value for the plot and then grab a global variable which is updated elsewhere.

```
mTimer1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            graph1LastXValue += 1d;
            airPressureSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(graph1LastXValue, 
               airPressureValue), true, graph1Num);
            fluidPressureSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(graph1LastXValue, 
               fluidPressureValue), true, graph1Num);
            graph2LastXValue += 1d;
            airTemperatureSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(graph2LastXValue, 
               airTemperatureValue), true, graph2Num);
            fluidTemperatureSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(graph2LastXValue
               , fluidTemperatureValue), true, graph2Num);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer1, 5);
```

The global variable is updated after new data has been received and parsed by an AsyncTask. In the doInBackground of the AsyncTask it assigns the parsed values to the global variables like this.

```
DeviceControlActivity.airPressureValue = airPressure;
DeviceControlActivity.airTemperatureValue = airTemperature;
DeviceControlActivity.fluidPressureValue = fluidPressure;
DeviceControlActivity.fluidTemperatureValue = fluidTemperature;
```

I have done a few things to check what's going on. I am certain that the timer is running fast enough to update the values. I am also certain that data is being received at the correct rate. I used logging to make sure of that. I also am sure that the async task in running and completing in a reasonable amount of time. In the post execute for it I told it to log the amount of time passed between pre and post execute function calls. It was consistently 1 ms which is fine for the application.

I think the issue has to do with how the values are set or retrieved. Based on the way the code inside the timer works it plots a new point even if the data has not been updated so I get regions of the plot that are all the same value for some amount of time greater than is reasonable.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might want to read up on Handlers to see why this wouldn't work to get any sort of precision timing. Keep in mind that Android is not an RTOS, and 100Hz is quite ambitious for collecting data AND graphing it. I would design a rock solid acquisition queue/buffer, and then update the UI at no more than 5Hz.

Comment: @323go The exact timing is not important. A timing jitter of as large as 20% of the intended sample rate wouldn't bother me. The issue isn't the timing at all. As far as I can tell it's the fact that for large fractions of a second the values to be plotted remain unchanged despite other sections of the program which are _supposed_ to update them having completed multiple times.

Comment: You're not going to get anywhere near 20% with the above code -- it's assuming that the data acquisition takes 5ms, and then adds another 5ms delay. That first assumption has no merit, and even if it's accurate on the development device, the moment you move to different hardware, that would change. As far as other things changing... well, you *are* dealing with passing data through global variables, which is fraught with all manner of issues. At least declare them `volatile` to assure instant updates.